# Average Repurchase Rate with weeks after Date of First Purchase

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Searching blogs, questions and answers, it seems that most of them are just *related* to my problem, but never quite answer my question really. Thus thanks a million for anyone who takes the time to help!

I work with SQL Server management studio 2008 R2.

I want to compare the “average repurchase rate” of clients. Repurchase rate (RPR) is calculated as the number of orders since date of his/her first orders.

Sample Table

- CustomerID  / OrderDate / VKR_Number
- D10001  / 2013-01-04  / VKR-1
- D10001  / 2013-05-01  / VKR-2
- D10001  / 2013-05-11  / VKR-3
- D10001  / 2013-08-01  / VKR-4

**Definitions**:
Cumulative Count (Repurchase):
Number of orders since first order; this is equivalent to total number of orders minus 1(i.e. first order)

**Repurchase Rate (RPR)**: Cumulative Count (Repurchase)/ [time interval]

RPR is exemplified in the table above:
customer D10001 has a cumulative RPR of

- count (VKR) = 1 in the 17 weeks since his/her first purchase on OrderDate = '2013-01-04'
- count (VKR) = 2 in the 18 weeks since his/her first purchase on OrderDate = '2013-01-04'
- count (VKR) = 3 in the 30 weeks since his/her first purchase on OrderDate = '2013-01-04'

The simplest version (for the TSQL layman at least) seems:

```
`Select CustomerID,  COUNT([VKR_]) over (Partition by customer, DATEDIFF(week, Min([OrderDate ]), [OrderDate ])) as CountOfOrders, DATEDIFF(week, Min([OrderDate ]), [OrderDate ]) as WeeksPassedSinceDateOfFirstPurchase`
```

The desired result Table would look like

- CustomerID  / WeeksPassedSinceDateOfFirstPurchase/ CountOfOrders
- D10001  / 17  / 1
- D10001  / 18  / 2
- D10001  / 30  / 3

If the above request is too difficult to achieve in TSQL, I also would be happy to get a result table like

- CustomerID  / WeeksPassedSinceDateOfFirstPurchase/ CountOfOrders
- D10001  / 1  / 0
- D10001  / 2  / 0
- D10001  / 3  / 0
- D10001  / 4  / 0
- D10001  / 5  / 0
- D10001  / 6  / 0
- etc
- D10001  / 17  / 1
- D10001  / 18  / 2
- D10001  / 19  / 2
- D10001  / 20  / 2
- D10001  / 21  / 2
- etc
- D10001  / 29  / 2
- D10001  / 30  / 3

Again, thank you very much for any advice! And apologies, if I missed any blog/answers, that had solved my problem already.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT CustID
    ,DATEDIFF(ww,OrderDate,GETDATE()) 'WEEKS'
    ,(SELECT COUNT(1) 
       from Table t2 
       where t1.custID=t2.custID 
          and t2.OrderDate<=t1.OrderDate 
       GROUP BY t2.CustID)-1 as CountOrders
FROM TABLE t1
GROUP BY CustID,OrderDate
ORDER BY OrderDate
```

From the question it does not look like you want an average, just a count -1, if that's not the case then please clarify.  This should give you the result table you asked for.  You may want to combine my second and third columns for the average orders per week if that is what you are getting at.

Comment: you may want to introduce order number if it is possible to have 2 orders on the same day...

Comment: Thanks.Correct, I am not looking for averages. I changed the statement such, that the DATEDIFF does not use GETDATE() but FirstOrderDate. `with cte as  (
Select Customer, [OrderDate] , MIN([OrderDate]) over (Partition by Customer) as FirstOrderDate, [VKR_]
FROM Table t1
   )
SELECT Customer
    ,DATEDIFF(ww,FirstOrderDate,[PostingDate]) 'WEEKS' etc. `   `

Comment: Problem: the count is not within the calculated time intervals (DATEDIFF) but counts ALWAYS Total of orders NOT cumulative! Please look again at Desired Table 1: there is 1 order after 17 weeks, 2 orders after 18 weeks, and finally 3 orders in 30 weeks. With the current statement I always get a count of 3. Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: Typo in my subquery where clause, and t2.OrderDate<=t2.OrderDate which i edited, that should fix the issue of not being cumulative. I used getdate as that gives you how many weeks have passed between now and each orderdate in the table.  that is certainly based on what info you want to see exactly.

Comment: The way you show weeks does make more sense based on the question.